# Node.js See Process Logs after server client console restart

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm using Amazon EC2 to host my Node.js server. I connect through ssh from my desktop, and once I run my server via ssh, I can turn my console off and everything will still work, obviously, since the process is running on my remote EC2 hosting server. But once I ssh again, I know the Node process is still running, but there seems to be no way to view the process logs, and this server is still in early beta versions that the console logs are important. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect stdout/stderr to a file, which would allow you to use ordinary tools like `cat` and `tail` to view the logs.

If you don't want to write the log output to file(s), you could start the process in `screen` or `tmux` or similar and attach to the session later from ssh.